# Why does subplot produce empty space on xaxis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have values at x and y axis and trying to produce simple line graph on subplot. Here is the simple and basic example which shows the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
      31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58,
      59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72]
y1 = [24.892730712890625, 25.268890380859375, 26.677642822265625, 28.294586181640625, 29.477203369140625,
      30.61334228515625, 31.656219482421875, 32.371551513671875, 31.412261962890625, 31.973724365234375, 31.563812255859375,
      30.72821044921875, 29.249237060546875, 26.759185791015625, 26.081024169921875, 25.27996826171875, 24.69805908203125,
      24.92388916015625, 24.76177978515625, 24.385498046875, 24.093231201171875, 23.92156982421875, 23.788543701171875,
      23.67657470703125, 23.581085205078125, 23.92095947265625, 25.90557861328125, 27.767333984375, 29.196136474609375,
      30.25726318359375, 31.262786865234375, 32.2996826171875, 32.92620849609375, 33.32098388671875, 33.228057861328125,
      30.495269775390625, 29.17010498046875, 28.04144287109375, 27.326202392578125, 24.904205322265625, 23.775054931640625,
      24.1328125, 24.195343017578125, 23.751312255859375, 23.55316162109375, 23.459228515625, 23.304534912109375,
      23.233062744140625, 23.093170166015625, 23.15887451171875, 25.13739013671875, 27.397430419921875, 28.923431396484375,
      29.945037841796875, 30.976715087890625, 31.93109130859375, 32.665435791015625, 32.701324462890625, 31.212799072265625,
      30.201507568359375, 29.591888427734375, 28.002410888671875, 27.72802734375, 27.371002197265625, 26.072509765625,
      25.39373779296875, 25.196044921875, 25.2684326171875, 24.815582275390625, 24.27130126953125, 23.758575439453125,
      23.49615478515625, 23.3907470703125]

plt.subplot(513)

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'b-')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

All works fine. But the output plot has some empty space on xaxis. Here is the image which shows the problem:-

[image: empty space on xaxis]

Any help to solve the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=You could use xlim to overwrite this behaviour introduced by "AutoLocator" in the background:

```
plt.subplot(513, xlim=(0,72))
# or
plt.subplot(513, xlim=(x1[0], x1[-1]))
```

You could also ajust the Locator like shown in this example (and others):
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo2.html

Comment: Both are correct. But I have chosen yours for giving me a simple and specific solution.

Comment: Where do you apply `xlim` to `plt.subplot2grid` function?

Answer (score 0):

By default, in matplotlib versions <2.0, matplotlib will choose "even" limits for the axes.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1977)

x = np.linspace(2.1, 22.8, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, x.size).cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you'd prefer to have the limits strictly set to the data limits, you can use `ax.axis('tight')`.  However, this will set both the x and y-limits to be "tight", which often is not what you want.

In this case, you'd more likely want to set just the x-limits to be "tight".  An easy way to do this is to use `ax.margins(x=0)`.  `margins` specifies that the autoscaling should pad things by a percentage of the data range.  Therefore, by setting `x=0`, we're effectively making the x-limits identical to the data limits in the x-direction.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1977)

x = np.linspace(2.1, 22.8, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, x.size).cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You could also accomplish this by using `ax.autoscale(axis='x', tight=True)`.

However, an additional advantage of `margins` is that you'll often want to have the y-axis pad by a percentage of the data range as well.  Therefore, it's common to want to do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1977)

x = np.linspace(2.1, 22.8, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, x.size).cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.margins(x=0, y=0.05)
plt.show()
```

[image]